# ∆G or ∆G° to predict spontaneity

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, free-energy

I have a doubt about using Gibbs free energy to predict the spontaneity of a reaction.

It is shown that ∆G = ∆G° + RT ln (Q).

That said, in order to predict which direction the reaction spontaneously goes, should ∆G or ∆G° be used? As I understand it, ∆G is what actually allows one to predict the spontaneity of the reaction, that is, whether the reaction proceeds spontaneously from the reactants to the products (in the direction written, ∆G < 0, exoergonic) or whether it proceeds spontaneously from the products to the reactants (in the opposite direction, ∆G > 0, endoergonic), and all of this depends on the value of Q, since ∆G° is constant. Instead, ∆G° should be used to understand how far the reaction is shifted to the right or left when it is at equilibrium (∆G = 0). However, very often I see that ∆G° is used to predict the spontaneity of a reaction, so I see a contradiction (especially in biochemistry, when it comes to reactions in which ATP is involved).

P.S. again referring to Gibbs free energy: can it be said that a process of mixing two substances is (almost) always characterized by a ∆S > 0 and therefore that the spontaneity of the process depends essentially on ∆H?

Comment: Prediction of reaction direction by $\Delta_r G^\circ $ is identical to prediction of reaction direction by $\Delta_r G $  at $Q=1$. The former is limited to $Q=1$, the latter is applicable to any $Q$. By other words, the former predicts reaction spontaneity generally, the latter in the particular case.

Comment: So, basically ∆G° allows you to see where the reaction is most shifted at equilibrium. 

Eventually it can also be used to predict the direction in which the reaction spontaneously proceeds, but only when the concentration of the reactants is equal to that of the products. For all other cases, ∆G is used.

Comment: Very often books refer to ∆G°: if ∆G° is positive, then the reaction is endoergonic and vice versa. But this is not entirely true, because the book does not refer to the specific case of Q=1. When I see ∆G° I think directly of the equilibrium situation (∆G=0)

Comment: Delta G0 is Delta G from Q=1 to Q=K.

Comment: What do you mean @Poutnik? Delta G^0 is Delta G for Q=K?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A process is called spontaneous when reacting in the forward direction would approach equilibrium (no matter whether a reaction in that direction is observed or not).

For a chemical reaction, this depends on the activities (concentrations and/or partial pressures) of reactants and products. To figure out whether a reaction under a given set of conditions (activities, temperature, pressure) is spontaneous in the forward or reverse direction, you have to know $\Delta_r G$.

Sometimes, people ask whether a certain reaction is spontaneous or not. The answer depends on the conditions, i.e. the activities of the reactants and products. If no set of conditions is given, you can answer that question by stating whether at standard conditions (i.e. Q = 1) and a temperature of choice the reaction is spontaneous in the forward or in the reverse direction. In that case, you would look at $\Delta_r G^\circ$ to determine which direction is spontaneous at standard conditions.

When a reaction proceeds in the absence of work, it approaches equilibrium; $\Delta_r G$ will continuously increase until it reaches zero at equilibrium.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't know if I'm getting it right. Basically, if you know that the reaction is taking place under *non* standard conditions, then to predict spontaneity you use ∆G and the equation ∆G = ∆G° + RT ln (Q): if you know Q (i.e., concentration of products and reactants, as you said), then it is easy to trace ∆G and thus spontaneity, since ∆G° is constant. So the reaction will proceed until ∆G cancels. Contextually, ∆G° gives us indications of how far the equilibrium is shifted, because at equilibrium ∆G is zero and ∆G° becomes directly related to Keq. And that's it so far.

Comment: Instead, when a reaction occurs under standard conditions, ∆G° can be used *both* to predict spontaneity, *both* to predict where equilibrium is shifted, taking advantage of the equation ∆G° = -RT ln Keq. For example, if Keq > 1, then ∆G° < 0 and the reaction is *both* exoergonic, *both* right-shifted at equilibrium. So in this case ∆G is not considered at all (?). However, previously we said that ∆G° is a constant: so in this case, of a reaction occurring under standard conditions, ∆G° should vary until it reaches zero, because it is now used to predict *even* spontaneity. Contradiction?

Comment: Starting with standard conditions, as soon as the reaction starts, you are no longer at standard conditions. The Gibbs energy of reaction changes continuously as the reaction proceeds. It is the derivative of the Gibbs energy with respect to the progress of reaction.

Comment: But doesn't the standard state, in the context of Gibbs free energy, depend only on pressure (1 atm)? It is sufficient to keep the pressure constant for the reaction to always run in the standard state.

Comment: No, the standard state has certain requirements for every reactant and product species: https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/S05925. See also https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/114651

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. I'll bring back an example:

Consider the following reaction and evaluate its spontaneity:

CaCO3 (s) --> CaO (s) + CO2 (g)

∆G = ∆G° + RT ln Q

If no pCO2 value is reported, then we take it as obvious that we are in standard conditions, so pCO2 = 1 atm and, consequently, Q=1 as well (solids have activity equal to 1). Consequently, ∆G = ∆G° and so ∆G° gives us information about where the reaction proceeds under these standard conditions. At equilibrium ∆G=0 and in this case ∆G° gives us information about where equilibrium is shifted.

Comment: Conversely, if we are told that pCO2 has a specific value, then we are not at standard conditions, Q≠1 and ∆G ≠ ∆G° and in this case we can only use ∆G to predict spontaneity. However, ∆G° always allows us to see where the equilibrium is shifted when ∆G =0.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in supposing that $\Delta_r G$ is what is important. A criterion for a spontaneous reaction is $\Delta_r G< 0$ and for equilibrium is when $\Delta_r G = 0$ so that $\Delta G^\text{o} =-RT\ln(K_e)$. Only here is $Q\equiv K_e$. At equilibrium the *change* of free energy is zero, it must be so, and the entropy is at a maximum.

Suppose that $\Delta G^\text{o}=0$ then the mixture of reactants and products is such that all have unit activity and are at equilibrium, and then $K_e=1$ as required by $\Delta G^\text{o} =-RT\ln(K_e)$ . If $\Delta G^\text{o} <0$ the mixture is not at equilibrium and this is now produced by reactants converting to products and the reaction proceeding to the right. As $\Delta G^\text{o} <0$ then $K_e >1$ which is just another way of saying that the reaction moves to the right. The larger $K_e$ becomes the further to the right the reaction reaches equilibrium.

If $\Delta G^\text{o} > 0$ then $K_e<1$ and the reaction does not proceed spontaneously and the equilibrium lies on the left.

(Your p.s. Mixing always does increase the entropy which via $-T\Delta S$ can have a big effect on the free energy but additionally reactions may increase or reduce the number of different gaseous species which also has a big effect on entropy changes.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But ∆G° is constant for a given reaction, how can it take values >, < or = to zero depending on the situation?

Also, the equation ∆G° = - RT ln Keq already refers to an equilibrium situation because the equation assumes that ∆G = 0. How can you say that if ∆G° > 0 then we are not at equilibrium? We may very well be at equilibrium but have a positive ∆G°. The ∆G° should only give information about how far the equilibrium is shifted to the left or right.... However I also refer you to the comment under Karsten's post.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood, of course, $\Delta G^\text{o}$ is fixed for a particular reaction. I gave examples of different values that cover all cases.  It is  $\Delta_r G$ (the slope of $G$ with extent of reaction) that varies until equilibrium is reached then it is zero.  $\Delta G^\text{o}$ is the standard state value and is fixed by what the molecule is and what conditions define it.